# Can't use peewee on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: osx, python, pip

I am getting an error when I run Python programs that imports peewee:

```
ImportError: No module named peewee
```

The same program works fine under Ubuntu 12.04.

I used pip to install peewee, and it confirms that it is installed:

```
$ pip install --upgrade peewee
Requirement already up-to-date: peewee in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the importing program using the right version of python?

Comment: Yes, running 2.7...

Comment: But is it using `/usr/local/bin/python`, or the system default, `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: No ... you are quite right! Changing the shebang solved the problem. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `peewee` module appears to be installed under `/usr/local`, but the OS X system default python lives in `/usr/bin`. Check the shebang line of the program that's failing, and make sure it's using the correct python.